# RDLC is clipped on next page in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc

I have one long report which contains 8 tablix. Now when the report needs another page for the records, it is clipping the records. I have set the page size to A4.

[image: Here is the image. The first few records are clipping.]

The first few records are clipped when printing. How to prevent this behaviour.  I am new to RDLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set top/bottom/left/right margins according to your printer.

I usually use this settings and never had problems (*Report > Report properties > Page setup*):

- left/right margin: 1,3cm
- bottom/top margins: 1,5cm

This is not connected to your problem but remember you need to set maximum report width according to these margins.